# Adding Endpoints in new Azure portal

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, endpoints

I have created a new Azure Classic Virtual Machine and when I try to access from my office its not able to connect. In previous versions of Azure I used to change the Endpoints to point to 443 public port. But in new portal i'm not sure where i need to change the Endpoints. Can you help in this regard? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you create a classic VM in new portal?

Comment: Now when I create a VM it doesn't ask for option of whether classic or Resource manager

Answer (score 0):

> But in new portal i'm not sure where i need to change the Endpoints.

If I understand it correctly, we can add endpoint here:

### [image]

**Update:**

It seems you create a ARM VM, if so, we can via Azure portal to add inbound security rules to NSG, like this:

[image]

[image]

More information about NSG, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal#create-rules-in-an-existing-nsg).

Comment: That option is not available in the current version..you will not be able see endpoints now.

Comment: @ArunS   I see, you created was ARM VM, we should add inbound rules of NSG, we can find NSG IN that resource group

Comment: @ArunS Does that work for you, please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: I created a VM with Windows R2 Server 2012 and Endpoints was available in it, but in 2016 it was not available. Will try the option you have specified and let you know for any further help.